# Add or change a value of JSON key with javascript in ember not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In .hbs file I'm trying to open a popup and using the code which contains .

template.hbs

```html
{{#each adultJsonArr as |adultTravellerDetails index|}}
    {{my-s3-uploader class = 'uploader-button'}}
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell-6-col ">
        {{#if (eq adultTravellerDetails.id_update_status 'available')}}
            <p>UPDATE ID Proof</p>
        {{/if}}
        {{#if (eq adultTravellerDetails.id_update_status 'never_added')}}
            <p>ADD ID Proof</p>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

So, now I'm trying to change the value of id_update_status in corresponding JS file using something like `this.adultJsonArr[0].id_update_status = 'updated'` So, it's not working. Instead if I try to change any other attribute it works like `this.adultJsonArr[0].id_update_status_check = 'Is it working?'` it works. It's basically like the json attribute which is not used at line no 4 and 7 in popup can be updated but one being used can't.

component.js

```js
importToCrs(response,uploadResponse){
     let file_path = $(uploadResponse).find('Location').html().toString();
     if( this.get('choice')=="adult"){
         this.adultJsonArr[this.get('choiceId')].traveller_id_proof_link = file_path ;
         this.adultJsonArr[this.get('choiceId')].id_update_status = 'updating' ;
     }
}
```

Updating traveller_id_proof_link is working but id_update_status is not working. How to handle it ?

Comment: That's true. If a computed property isn't used (in a template f.e.) it won't get updated. You can try to display it for demonstration purpose once. But please post the corresponding controller/component.js to get a good answer.

Comment: @Jeff updated!! can you look into it now.

Answer (score 3):

Hi can you show me how you initialized adultJsonArr?
It could be because the content inside the array might not be ember object.
Also it should be updated with setter I reckon.

May be try this:

```
this.get('adultJsonArr').objectAt(this.get('choiceId')).set('traveller_id_proof_link', 'updated');
```